# Using global string script variable in Run or other section in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need a global string variable in Inno Setup, that is going to be initialized in `[Code]` section and used in `[Run]` section.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

```pascal
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Parameters: "{code:GetGlobalVariable}"

[Code]

var
  GlobalVariable: string;

function GetGlobalVariable(Param: string): String;
begin
  Result := GlobalVariable;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  GlobalVariable := '/parameter';

  Result := True;
end;
```

---

For a more real-life example, see [Use a part of a registry key/value in the Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34680822/850848).

Comment: that is exacly what I was looking for! Thank you sooo much!!