# Use a part of a registry key/value in the Inno Setup script

Tags: inno-setup, registrykey

I have a need to retrieve a path to be used for some stuffs in the installer according an other application previously installed on the system.

This previous application hosts a service and only provides one registry key/value hosting this information: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\APPLICATION` hosting the value `ImagePath` which Data is `"E:\TestingDir\Filename.exe"`.

I need a way to only extract the installation path (`E:\TestingDir`) without the `Filename.exe` file.

Any suggestion?
thanks a lot

Comment: You would use pascal script; RegQueryStringValue() to get the path in a string, then use ExtractFileDir() to get the directory part

Comment: great idea!
Does the variable defined into the code section will be read in the Rn section as well? Not properly clear how to connect what is in run section with everything that is in the pascal code...thanks!

Comment: moreover the problem is that I need to read the value of the registry in the destination machine (where is installed) while the extractfiledir if I remember fine will extract the values in the compiling machine (source), isn't it?thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants).

You define a function that produces the value you need:

```pascal
[Code]

function GetServiceInstallationPath(Param: string): string;
var
  Value: string;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\APPLICATION',
       'ImagePath', Value) then
  begin
    Result := ExtractFileDir(Value);
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := { Some fallback value }
  end;
end;
```

And then you refer to it using `{code:GetServiceInstallationPath}` where you need it (like in the `[Run]` section).

For example:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{code:GetServiceIntallationPath}\SomeApp.exe"
```

---

Actually, you probably want to retrieve the value in [`InitializeSetup`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup) already, and cache the value in a global variable for use in the scripted constant. And abort the installation (by returning `False` from `InitializeSetup`), in case the other application is not installed (= the registry key does not exist).

```pascal
[Code]

var
  ServiceInstallationPath: string;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  Value: string;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\APPLICATION',
       'ImagePath', Value) then
  begin
    ServiceInstallationPath := ExtractFileDir(Value);
    Log(Format('APPLICATION installed to %s', [ServiceInstallationPath]));
    Result := True;
  end
    else
  begin
    MsgBox('APPLICATION not installed, aborting installation', mbError, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function GetServiceInstallationPath(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := ServiceInstallationPath;
end;
```

---

See also a similar question: [Using global string script variable in Run section in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33974745/850848).

Comment: Hi Martin,it helps me a lot!
More over the need is to skip installation if registry is not present: idea is that if the registry exists, to use the path to put some files in.
On the other hands instead, in case the registry not exists, to perform a set of operation (that at the end will generate the registry as well).
So InitializeSetup() is not helping in the case registry is not existing.
Is there any other function you suggest for this scope?
regards,

Comment: Function for what? I do not know what operations you need to do. It's a different question anyway, [ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and explain better.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this way:
[code]
    var
      ServiceInstallationPath: string;

```
function MyProgCheck(): Boolean;
var
  Value: string;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\JLR STONE VCATS TO MES',
       'ImagePath', Value) then
  begin
    ServiceInstallationPath := ExtractFileDir(Value);   
    Result := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

and in the [RUN] section I put as check the TRUE condition or FALSE condition on this function according the needs...Thanks everybody answering!