# Read destination directory from ini file during install time in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I need to read a directory path from an ini file at install time.

Under the `[Code]` section I have defined a function like

```pascal
function GetDirectoryFromIni: String;
begin
  Result := 
    GetIniString('Directories' , 'Name' ,
      ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Default_Path\' , 
      ExpandConstant('{app}')+'my_ini_file.ini');
end;
```

How can I use this function/path/string in the `[Files]` section?

Something like:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Source_Directory\*.*"; DestDir: "GetDirectoryFromIni"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion
```

The basic logic is if the user has changed the "Default_Path" from a previous installation I want to adjust to use it, otherwise it uses the default path when the program is first installed.

I cannot seem to define or set a string variable to use the `GetDirectoryFromIni` result.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this even without any Pascal Script code. There's [`{ini}` "constant"](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=ini):

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Source_Directory\*.*"; \
  DestDir: "{ini:{app}\my_ini_file.ini,Directories,Name|{app}\Default_Path\}"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion
```

---

For an answer for your expected solution, see:
[Using global string script variable in Run or other section in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33974745/850848)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the function in the [Files] section like

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Source_Directory\*.*"; DestDir: "{code:GetDirectoryFromIni}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Then it works.